# Google Secret Manager Permissions For Local Emulating of Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I've given the service account for the functions the necessary permissions ('Secret Manager Secret Accessor') and when deployed, the firebase functions are able to access the secrets without any problems.

However, when using `firebase serve` or `firebase emulators:start --only functions` in local development, I'm getting the following error

> Unhandled error Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource

I've found in the documentation that setting `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=pathtoserviceaccount.json` is needed to be entered in the terminal, though this did also not work for me.

I would be thankful for all pointers. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer myself:
When the functions are emulated locally, they do not get run by the `App Engine default service account` per default, this needs to be enabled as well.
So I had to follow this tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell

The `App Engine default service account` needs a key which can be created in the Service Accounts settings in the Google Cloud, and then
I had to enter

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"`

in the terminal. By running then `firebase emulators:start` they also got permission to access the Secret Manager.

So while I was on the right track, I was exporting the wrong Service Account key, and not the one that was allowed to run access the Secret Manager.

Comment: thanks fro the tip! I found similar instructions in the [functions emulator docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and tried the solution from pureth's answer to adding local overrides, but it didn't work. What did work for me was to create the `.secret.local` file in the functions directory, not in the project root.

My project structure is as follows:

```
/
|- .firebaserc
|- firebase.json
|- package.json
|- /* ... */
|- functions/
   |- .secret.local
   |- package.json
   |- /* ... */
```

So the `.secret.local` file needs to be placed in the directory where your functions reside and not where the `.firebaserc` file is.

Also, please note that the file name starts with a dot.

Answer (score 5):

"[...] you can override secrets values by setting up a `.secret.local` file. This makes it easy for you to test your functions locally, especially if you don't have access to the secret value."

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secrets_and_credentials_in_the_emulator

Step by step:

1. make sure you have the latest version of `firebase-tools` installed, as this feature is relatively new.
2. Create a file named `.secret.local` in the root of your firebase project (along side the `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json`
3. add your secrets to the file, formatted the same as way as a regular `.env` file. e.g.

```
MY_SECRET_1=foo
MY_SECRET_2=bar
```

4. run the emulator `firebase emulators:start`
5. within your firebase functions, access the secrets on the process object. e.g. `process.env.MY_SECRET_1`

> note, as far as I can tell, the secrets are only available inside the block scope of a function handler. you can't access them in the root scope of your functions JS code (if somebody finds a way to do that, please comment here as I'd love to know too)

Comment: Can you provide more info on this, how to set the .secret.local file? The link doesn't provide any example.

Comment: sure, i'll update the comment now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Btw, would this also work with GCP only projects?

Answer (score 2):

In order to access Secret Manager from your Firebase application running with local emulator you need to add role of:

- "**Secret Manager Secret Accessor**" to **YOUR account** used to authenticate with Firebase

You can verify it by running: `firebase login` in local CLI.

If you're already logged in, it should respond with `Already logged in as [email address]`.

This email address is the Principal account you need to add the role to.

As you've mentioned in your question the "firebase-adminsdk" service account permissions are used on the production deployment, but not on local, unless you specify it with: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"`